# Android fingerprint

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am a newbie in android development
I am developing an android app that allow people using fingerprint to check-in. The idea is, for instance, a class need student check-in on time everyday. Student have to register their fingertip to identify with application.
I don't know whether android support my application? I just saw that fingerprint identify using registered user's finger.
Could you please help me some idea?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi You can try this link. Might be helpful for you

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

Comment: For now Android is supporting only fingerprints that user had setup in his phone settings. So you can just verify that given fingerprint is of phone's user or not

Comment: @Mayur_Thakur: can I detect which finger if I had setup many fingerprints?

Comment: I think NO. But you can verify given fingerprint is authorised or not

Comment: @Mayur_Thakur: I have found this article: https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal   but I dont know it is possible or not. could you help to check?

Comment: If you want to just authenticate the fingerprints that are saved in user's phone then I can share you my code

Comment: @Mayur_Thakur: very thank you, I already authenticate registered user but I hope can detect which fingerprint is scanner. Its seem not possible for now. May be android will support in the future

Answer (score 0):

Android supports detecting more than one fingerprint.
Eg:Coolpad note 3 detects 5 different fingerprints and we can assign different actions to each fingerprint.
i.e one for unlock screen,one for camera.

- Detecting and authentication of different fingerprint is based on how you code your application.So go forward.

[You can find here the code for the implentation of Fingerprint authentication in an app](https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-fingerprint-authentication-to-your-android-app-747304/amp/)

- remember one thing that,here you can login in your app only using the fingerprint that you have used for the device's screen lock.

Answer (score 0):

Android authorizes or verifies a user if the fingerprint was previously registered through Android settings. Meaning, you can't add new fingerprints through your app.

The KeyStore save all the keys and use the Keystore private key to sign transactions / data. Meaning, you cannot differentiate users through your app.